# How to make TLS resumption work in the .Net framework?

Tags: tls1.2, ftps

I have C# code that uploads a file to an FTP server. Now TLS 1.2 is used and I adapted the code for this, but there is still a problem with TLS session resumption.
According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/transport-layer-security-tls-connections-might-fail-or-timeout-when-connecting-or-attempting-a-resumption-326bd5b1-52a1-b367-8179-b154e5c01e90) link Microsoft plugged a TLS hole by disabling the resume by an update in 2019. To let it work they describe that “Extend Master Secret” should be used. As far I could search this is the exchange of some keys between client and server to guarantee the client did not change.
But exactly how do you implement this in C#, does anyone have an example of this or can refer to some documentation ?
Your help is highly appreceated